# 404 page if submitting an edit suggestion to a post that already has one

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, 404-not-found, 500-server-error

If in the course of writing an edit suggestion another user submits a suggestion on the same post first, submitting your suggestion leads to a 404 page. As does going back to the edit page, because `/posts/#/edit` returns a 404 if you don't have edit rights and suggesting an edit is blocked for whatever reason. `/posts/#/edit-submit` (and probably `/edit` too) should say something like "You can't suggest an edit because another edit is already in the queue/the queue is full/etc."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed this so it displays a text message:

"There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes."