# Missing 'edit' link - show 'edit pending' instead of removing 'edit' link for rep<2000

Tags: bug, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [404 page if submitting an edit suggestion to a post that already has one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95261/404-page-if-submitting-an-edit-suggestion-to-a-post-that-already-has-one)

I just got really confused.  I edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424544/java-run-multiple-shell-commands/7424580#7424580), and after trying to save I got sent to a 'page does not exist' page.

Going back to the answer, the 'edit' link is gone (for me).  Searching meta, it would appear that the reason for this is that there is a pending edit from another user and as I'm not yet 2000 rep so don't have any way to see pending edits.  Is this correct?

If correct, wouldn't it be better if there was a landing page explaining that there's a pending edit?

Also wouldn't it be better to show a non-linked 'edit pending' text (see below image) instead of having no link at all?

[image]

Comment: You know you could have just removed the duplicate bit (which was only the 1st sentence) and kept the feature request bit (which is not a duplicate).  Editing a key part of SO, but not meta it seems.