# How are conflicting Edits resolved?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, suggested-edits

I edited (well, suggested an edit) to a post.  Upon completing my edit, I expected to see the normal message about my edit pending peer review.  Instead it just took me to the question and showed "edited by Farray".  It took me a moment to realize that the edit displayed was not my handiwork.

Upon reviewing [the question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7831442/revisions), I found no record of my suggested edits to the title and body of the question, but my name was listed next to an "edited tags" record.  I did not edit any tags.  Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you found a bug, but it's a little confusing. Your edit is at the same moment as kay's suggestion approval, and the approval lists Community as one of the approvers, which are both signs of an improved suggestion. I think what happened is:

- You started editing
- kay submitted a suggestion
- You submitted a similar suggestion, but didn't retag like he did
- The system misinterpreted your suggestion as an editor selecting the "improve" option (even though you don't have enough rep to approve edit suggestions anyway). It applied your edits on top of kay's, which resulted in you adding back the tag he had removed

It's already established that editors can [accidentally mark edit suggestions improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88186/collision-detection-fails-when-saving-while-suggested-edits-are-pending) this way, but the system shouldn't have let you improve an edit suggestion without enough rep (and [typically doesn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95261/404-page-if-submitting-an-edit-suggestion-to-a-post-that-already-has-one)). The suggestion also shows up as approved by 3 people, but I'm not sure where that came from

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, since this bug report is now ancient, I can't repro this. Following the repro steps by Michael simply returns a *"Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed."* message box.