# Don't show me suggestions if someone is currently editing it

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Ever so often, there is a suggested edit that I choose to edit. However, when I click submit, nearly always I will get the notice saying the post was edited by someone else and that my edit must be a radical change to override their's.

This is often times annoying as I just put in effort to fix a post only to be prevented from doing it. I understand the reasoning for my edit needing to be more of a change, but I think we should prevent people from editing a suggested edit or even just not show it while someone else is editing.

As for how, maybe when someone clicks the "Edit" button, *hide* the suggested edit from the queue for (say) 5 minutes. If they click "Cancel" in the meantime, just "unhide" it for others to see. Maybe we could use AJAX to ping the server every 5 minutes to say we're still editing. If it doesn't receive the ping, then it could assume they closed out of it, and then it could be "unhid".

Comment: So, if someone starts an edit and goes to dinner...?

Comment: @Oded put a timeout or something then.

Comment: See the answer here for a good example of the mess this can make: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166861/can-we-get-a-better-conflict-resolution-to-edits-vs-suggested-edits

Comment: Its "difficult" programmatically to add a timeout and hold the editing to others, and maybe is easy to attack to the system by open all the time the editing on all questions, or on many questions. Maybe just a message that other also editing at the same time - no block out, just a message

Comment: @Oded add something like "are you still there?" or a timeout.

Comment: You may be seeing [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/improving-a-suggested-edit-that-has-been-approved-in-the-meantime-leads-to-a-dea), which prevents improvements even if they don't conflict.

Comment: @ColeJohnson because the one is older and the feature requests are effectively the same.  You wanted to close the other as a duplicate of this one, so I could ask you the same

Comment: @ColeJohnson yours is older?  Did you check the dates?  Oct 9 2012 vs May 14 2013?