# Don't award reputation for tag edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

Now that the tag editing privilege has been removed, tag edits go through the Suggested Edits queue.

The problem is that users are suggesting edits that are *pure* tag edits. I'm sure most are in good faith and not trying to game the system, but there are usually other problems with the post. The suggested action is to either reject as "Too Minor" or to improve the edit.

The problem is that I don't want to award the reputation when there are other problems with the post. I want the user to *learn* that minor edits are discouraged. However, sometimes, their tag edit is *really good*. So, I want to keep that tag edit, but I don't want to award the reputation. The only thing I can do is look for something else that can be changed (like removing a "Thanks"), fixing it, and unchecking the "Suggested Edit was helpful" box.

However, [as detailed in my other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180216/dont-show-me-suggestions-if-someone-is-currently-editing-it), that soon becomes a problem. Especially with users who click through to earn badges with no regards to quality!

I also feel that having an edit rejected due to my "improvement" can discourage users. That's not what we want! We *want* users to improve the site through editing!

We need a way to approve tag edits without discouraging users by rejecting. The only way to due this currently is to approve them. The flaw with that, as mentioned above, is that the user *doesn't learn*.

I propose we keep tag edits going through the queue, but either don't award reputation, or only award **one** rep point.

*Who's with me?!*

Comment: Not sure what I think yet, but you might as well bring back the tag edit privilege if you do this

Comment: @psubsee2003 but there are some tag edits that are _actually bad_. Having a review queue helps with those cases.

Comment: I know, but they can be bad for 2K users too.  Like I said, I'm not sure how I feel about this.  I'm wondering if we can get any stats to suggest how many tag only edits are netting +2 rep for someone and if it is really a problem.

Comment: +1. I've seen too many users try to slap the same tag on a whole list of questions, without any effort to improve the rest of the post.

Comment: @S.L.Barth but that specific case is usually a lame attempt to get a badge in that tag - I'd bet that in a lot of those cases the tag editor also has an answer. Which is arguably a slightly different problem.